# How can I require modules with patterns in the path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I include all files in nodeJS like

```
require('./packages/city/model/cities')
require('./packages/state/model/states')
require('./packages/country/model/countries')
```

like as

```
require('./packages/*/model/*')
```

same like grunt is loading files.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't (or at least you shouldn't)**

In order to do this, you would have to overload node's native `require` function, which is highly inadvisable.

The CommonJS pattern might seem tedious to you, but it's a very good one and you shouldn't try to break it just because you saw shortcuts in other languages/frameworks.

By introducing some form of magic in your module, you suddenly change everything that programmers can (and should be able to) safely assume about the CommonJS pattern itself.

Answer (score 2):

Due to one-to-one correspondence in node module loading system, it wont be possible natively, but would not be surprised if there is a package for this method.

Best you can do is create a index.js that loads modules present in directory and exports them as its own.

```
module.exports = function() {
   return {
        city : require('./city/model/'),
        state : require('./packages/state/model/'),
        country : require('./packages/country/model/')
   }
}
```

you would have to load models in similary fashion in all three dirrectories as well.

I know that this solution is not what you are looking for but in my experirence, this method allows to better manage custom packages as you can add/remove features easily.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js's `require` allows you to

1. load only one module at a time
2. load modules only in synchronous fashion.

That is how the module system works in Node.js. But if you want to have minimatch kind of matching functionality, you can roll one on your own, like this

```
var path = require("path"),
    glob = require("glob");

function requirer(pattern) {
    var modules = {},
        files = glob.sync(pattern);

    files.forEach(function(currentFile) {
        var fileName = path.basename(currentFile);
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".js"));
        modules[fileName] = require(currentFile);
    });

    return modules;
}
```

This depends on `glob` module, which allows you to use minimatch patterns to search files and then we require the found files, store them in an object and return the object. And this can be used like this

```
var modules = requirer('./packages/*/model/*.js');
console.log(modules.cities);
```

**P.S:** I am working on making this a [public module](https://github.com/thefourtheye/require-minimatch) already.